# How to fix the "Warning: useLayoutEffect does nothing on the server"?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-hooks, react-testing-library

Heres the full error:

> Warning: useLayoutEffect does nothing on the server, because its
> effect cannot be encoded into the server renderer's output format.
> This will lead to a mismatch between the initial, non-hydrated UI and
> the intended UI. To avoid this, useLayoutEffect should only be used in
> components that render exclusively on the client
>
> ```
>       in ForwardRef(ButtonBase)
>       in WithStyles(ForwardRef(ButtonBase))
>       in ForwardRef(Button)
>       in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Button))
>       in form
>       in div
> ```

I get it every time I run my test.  Heres my test

```
/* eslint-disable quotes */
import React from "react"
import { shallow, configure } from "enzyme"
import LoginForm from "../src/components/LoginForm"
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button"
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16"
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react"

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

describe("<LoginForm />", () => {
  let wrapper
  let usernameInput
  let passwordInput
  let signInButton

  // Create initial props that get passed into the component
  const initialProps = {
    location: {
      state: {
        from: {
          pathname: "/",
        },
      },
    },
  }

  // Unit testing
  describe("Unit tests", () => {
    // what to do before each test
    beforeEach(() => {
      // Render the login form component, pass in props. (Shallow method renders the component without its children, good for unit tests.)
      wrapper = shallow(<LoginForm {...initialProps} />)
      usernameInput = wrapper.find("#username")
      passwordInput = wrapper.find("#password")
      signInButton = wrapper.find(Button)
    })

    // what to do after each test
    afterEach(() => {
      jest.clearAllMocks()
    })

    // UI Integrity test
    it("should match the snapshot", () => {
      // snapshots are text references of the html of the rendered component.
      expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot()
    })

    it("should have a username inputs", () => {
      expect(usernameInput.length).toEqual(1)
    })

    it("should have the expected props on the username field", () => {
      expect(usernameInput.props()).toEqual({
        id: "username",
        name: "username",
        value: "",
        type: "username",
        onChange: expect.any(Function),
        required: true,
      })
    })

    it("should have a password field", () => {
      expect(passwordInput.length).toEqual(1)
    })

    it("should have the expected props on the password field", () => {
      expect(passwordInput.props()).toEqual({
        id: "password",
        name: "password",
        value: "",
        type: "password",
        onChange: expect.any(Function),
        required: true,
      })
    })

    it("should have a submit button", () => {
      expect(signInButton.length).toEqual(1)
    })

    it("should have the expected props on the button", () => {
      expect(signInButton.props()).toEqual({
        type: "button",
        variant: "contained",
        style: expect.objectContaining({
          marginTop: "10px",
        }),
        onClick: expect.any(Function),
        children: "Sign In",
      })
    })
  })

  // Integrations Testing
  describe("Integrations tests", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      // Render the login form component, pass in props. (render method renders the component with its children, good for integrations tests, uses react-test-library.)
      const { getByLabelText, getByText } = render(
        <LoginForm {...initialProps} />
      )
      usernameInput = getByLabelText(/Username/i)
      passwordInput = getByLabelText(/Password/i)
      signInButton = getByText("Sign In")
    })

    afterEach(cleanup)

    it("Username text change in onChange event", () => {
      expect(usernameInput.value).toBe("")

      fireEvent.change(usernameInput, { target: { value: "James" } })

      expect(usernameInput.value).toBe("James")
    })

    it("Password text change in onChange event", () => {
      expect(passwordInput.value).toBe("")

      fireEvent.change(passwordInput, { target: { value: "mypassword" } })

      expect(passwordInput.value).toBe("mypassword")
    })

    it("Test button submit", () => {
      const mockLogin = jest.fn()

      const button = shallow(<Button onClick={mockLogin} />)

      button.simulate("click")

      expect(mockLogin.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1)
    })
  })
})
```

I believe it has something to do with the material-ui component.  I've looked into it, theres a similar question on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57268689/how-to-fix-this-warning-uselayouteffect-related-warning) that says the issue has to do with a dependency that my project does not have.  So I think it has to do with the material-ui component using `useEffectLayout` and the testing env doesnt like that for some reason.  Im running my test with yarn and jest `yarn test` to run the test suite.

Comment: you may workaround by specifying env for tests https://gist.github.com/gaearon/e7d97cdf38a2907924ea12e4ebdf3c85#gistcomment-2911761 like `/* @jest-environment node */`

Comment: Is `<LoginForm ... />` a HOC? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Hey @skyboyer, thanks for that tip.  I had actually tried doing just that before: adding  ```"jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }``` to my package.json file.  But it gave a new issue when running yarn test:
```ReferenceError: window is not defined

      24 | // })
      25 |
    > 26 | jest.spyOn(window.localStorage.__proto__, "setItem")
         |            ^
      27 | window.localStorage.__proto__.setItem = jest.fn()
      28 |

      at Object.window (src/setupTests.js:26:12)
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)```
So Im looking into that now...

Comment: ok, so I couldnt get rid of the above `window not defined problem` when adding the node jest-environement.  But what did work for me was a comment in your like @skyboyer, that said adding ```import React from "react"
React.useLayoutEffect = React.useEffect``` to my setup file would work.  And it did.  Its hacky, but whatever.

Comment: hi @LCIII it is not a HOC

Comment: jkeary I did not think about such a trick! if you compose official answer I'll definitely upvote it :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

adding

```
import React from "react" 
React.useLayoutEffect = React.useEffect
```

to my frontend/src/setupTests.js test file is a way to suppress the jest warning.  Ultimately, this looks to be an issue with Material-UI components having issues with Jest.

Comment: This is beautiful

Comment: ... is it really?
It looks like useLayoutEffect overwrites useEffect.

Comment: This literally changes the reference for `useLayoutEffect` to `useEffect`.  Don't do this unless you think every place you used `useLayoutEffect` was a mistake but for some inane reason you don't feel like switching the references to `useEffect` (basically: do the right thing, not this).

Answer (score 28):

A bit cleaner solution might be to use jest mock like so:

```
jest.mock('react', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react'),
  useLayoutEffect: jest.requireActual('react').useEffect,
}));
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it actually works in all cases and is the proper "mocking" way of doing things. Ignore the accepted answer above.

Comment: In Next JS, no need to import React explicitly, hence this one is more fashion.

Comment: This one gives `error - ./node_modules/@jest/core/build/collectHandles.js:10:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks'` Does anybody know how to fix it? I tried adding async_hooks as a dependency, to no avail.

Comment: What file do we put this in? I'm guessing it has to be a global file that applies to all tests?

Update: It can go in your `setupTests.js file` if you have one. See: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#initializing-test-environment

Answer (score 11):

you should check if the useLayoutEffect can be used this way:

```
import React, {useEffect, useLayoutEffect} from 'react';

const canUseDOM = typeof window !== 'undefined';
const useIsomorphicLayoutEffect = canUseDOM ? useLayoutEffect : useEffect;
```

then instead of the `useLayoutEffect` use a `useIsomorphicLayoutEffect`

Comment: This works outside of tests, so can be used for server-side rendering.

Answer (score 6):

You can fix this by adding the following if statement to the beginning of your startup file (e.g. index.js):

```
if (typeof document === 'undefined') {
  React.useLayoutEffect = React.useEffect;
}
```

This will ensure that the SSR uses `React.useEffect` instead of `React.useLayoutEffect` because `document` is undefined on the server-side.