Trying to mock AdvancedMarkerElement from google.maps.MarkerLibrary
We are trying to test the AdvancedMarkerElement from the Google Maps API. We replaced google.maps.Markers with AdvancedMarkerElement. The tests we had originally were using @googlemaps/jest-mocks' and we mocked the listener and then called it directly using addListenerSpy.mock.calls[0][1]() and then assert that the proper calls were made.
Below is the test which was working with Markers:
/* global jest context */
import { render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'
import { initialize } from '@googlemaps/jest-mocks'
import '@googlemaps/react-wrapper'

import { useSessionContext } from 'hooks/SessionContext'

import Map from 'pages/Dashboard/CriticalAndMajorAlertsMapCard/Map'

jest.mock('hooks/SessionContext')

jest.mock('@googlemaps/markerclusterer', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@googlemaps/markerclusterer'),
  MarkerClusterer: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {})
}))

//  mocking useLayoutEffect to use useEffect useLayoutEffect is intended to be used within a browser like environment
//  and jest runs test in node .env by default which doesn't provide a browser DOM.
//  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58070996/how-to-fix-the-warning-uselayouteffect-does-nothing-on-the-server
//  https://react.dev/reference/react/useLayoutEffect#im-getting-an-error-uselayouteffect-does-nothing-on-the-server

jest.mock('react', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react'),
  useLayoutEffect: jest.requireActual('react').useEffect
}))

const dealer = Object.freeze({
  dealerId: 1,
  latitude: 40.15,
  longitude: -111.11
})

const devices = Object.freeze({
  deviceId: '12345ABCD',
  criticalAlertCount: 1,
  majorAlertCount: 1,
  sdaMajorAlertCount: 0
})

const customersWithLocation = Object.freeze(
  [{
    customerId: 1,
    dealerId: 2,
    latitude: 35.01,
    longitude: -113.45,
    devices: [devices]
  }]
)

describe('Map', () => {
  context('when map loads', () => {
    const addListenerSpy = jest.fn()
    const openInfoWindowSpy = jest.fn()
    const setContentinfoWindowSpy = jest.fn()

    beforeEach(() => {
      useSessionContext.mockReturnValue({
        session: dealer
      })

      initialize()
      window.google.maps.Marker = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
          addListener: addListenerSpy
        }
      })

      window.google.maps.InfoWindow = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
          setContent: setContentinfoWindowSpy,
          open: openInfoWindowSpy
        }
      })
    })

    describe('when user clicks on the customer marker', () => {
      it('opens info window for customer ', async () => {
        render(<Map customersWithLocation={customersWithLocation} />)

        addListenerSpy.mock.calls[0][1]()

        await waitFor(() => {
          expect(setContentinfoWindowSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
          expect(openInfoWindowSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
        })
      })
    })
  })
})

When we switched to using AdvancedMarkerElement we had to import the library like so:
 const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = (await google.maps.importLibrary('marker')) as google.maps.MarkerLibrary

We could not figure out how to mock this using Jest mocks so what we wound up doing is creating a file that contains this functionality and then are trying to mock the file we just implemented. The AdvancedMarkerElement importer file is:
export const importAdvancedMarkerElement = async () => {
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = (await google.maps.importLibrary('marker')) as google.maps.MarkerLibrary
  return AdvancedMarkerElement
}

We have tried mocking the above like so:
jest.mock('pages/Dashboard/CriticalAndMajorAlertsMapCard/AdvancedMarkerElement', () => {
  return {
    importAdvancedMarkerElement: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        addListener: jest.fn()
      }
    })
  }
})

But are now getting the following error when running:
    TypeError: AdvancedMarkerElement is not a constructor

      54 |           }
      55 |
    > 56 |           const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({


The real importAdvancedMarkerElement  returns a class, which you new up, but the test double returns a vanilla object with a single method. What would you expect from new { addListener() {} }?

Thank you for responding. I struggle with Javascript. What would the proper syntax be to return an object that meets the criteria for above?

https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks
